# fake EF DBContext in Visual Basic.NET

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I found solution for faking DBContext in C#. Creating an Interface IDbContext. For production code I create a LifeDbContext that inherit from DbContext and implement IDbContext. For unit testing I create a class FakeDbContext that implements also IDbContext and fake the Datebase with Collections ... fine.

But now I have to do it with Visual Basic.NET. Because of I have to implicitly implement each member of the interface IDbContext I can not implement the members of DbContext base class.
In c# there is no need to explicit implement a member of an interface.

Any idea?

Here my code:

```
Public Interface IMyDbContext
  Property Orders As IDbSet(Of Oders)
  ...

  ReadOnly Property Database() As Database
  Function SaveChanges() As Integer
  ReadOnly Property Configuration As Infrastructure.DbContextConfiguration
End Interface


Public Class MyDbContext
  Inherits DbContext
  Implements IDbContext

  Public Property Orders As IDbSet(Of Orders) Implements IMyDbContext.Oders
  ...

  Public ReadOnly Property Database() As Database Implements ILimsDbContext.Database
    Get
        Return MyBase.Database
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Function SaveChanges() As Integer Implements IMyDbContext.SaveChanges
      Return MyBase.SaveChanges()
  End Function

  Public ReadOnly Property Configuration() As Infrastructure.DbContextConfiguration Implements IMyDbContext.Configuration
    Get
        Return MyBase.Configuration
    End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

What I don't like is the shadowing the already in DbContext implemented members in MyDbContext only for explicit implement the interface.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the t4 template to add your interfaces and implements clauses, but that would lock you into your customized t4 implementation. I did something along these lines in a post on adding property logging a while back. See if [this post](http://www.thinqlinq.com/default/Adding-Property-Get-logging-to-LINQ-to-SQL-with-T4.aspx) is helpful.